# работаю с aiogram , сложности с с пересылкой сообщения в группу

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

`await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Введите номер ?') await bot.send_message(CHANEL_ID, 'number : ')`
Я новичок в python , учусь писать бота , не могу решить проблему с пересылкой ,
как сделать пересылку того что пользователь введет в  строке , либо inlinebutton которую он выберет группу в телеграмме ?

Comment: Выложите весь код, ничего не понятно

Comment: async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
            await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Введите номер :', reply_markup=inline_kb3)
            await bot.send_message(CHANEL_ID, 'number : ')

Comment: Не в комментарии, а в вопрос. Для этого есть ссылка [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1327547/edit)